# How to send ether to an account instead of creating a smart contract using ethers.js

Tags: transactions, ether, contract-invocation, javascript, ethereumjs

I would like to send some ether to an account in ropsten testnet. I'm using the following code and the library https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/. However, instead of sending the ether to the `to` account, it is creating a contract. What am I doing wrong?

```
const wallet = new Wallet(config.privateKey);
wallet.provider = ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider('ropsten');


const transaction = {
    nonce: 0,
    gasLimit: config.gasLimit,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    to: to,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount),
    // data: "0x",
    // This ensures the transaction cannot be replayed on different networks
    chainId: 3 // ropsten
};

const signedTransaction = wallet.sign(transaction);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    wallet.sendTransaction(signedTransaction)
        .then(function(hash) {
            logTransaction(hash, config.sourceAddress, to, amount, gasPrice);
            resolve(hash);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
});
```

This is an example transaction created by running the code above:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x79504f592a390cdf36dab6f1ee196bf94cab7b032b0b88caf8e6bccdb2a76dbb

EDIT: the problem comes from signing the transaction. If I do not sign the transaction, `sendTransaction(transaction)` works as expected and funds are transferred to `to`. If I sign the transaction and do `sendTransaction(signedTransaction)` it creates the mentioned contracts. What is the purpose of signing it, and why is it making the transaction to "fail"?

Comment: Print out the value of `to`? My guess is that it's `null` or `0`.

Comment: The value of to is:  0x00269e08097635F95aba776030e0907b56a7e181. Neither null nor 0. Maybe it needs some specific format or smthing like that?

Comment: Ok, I've seen that the to field becomes undefined after signing the transaction. Is that normal, or what is the expected behaviour

Comment: You mean the `transaction` object gets modified? Can you show code and output where you're doing `console.log(transaction.to)` above and below the `sign` call?

Comment: I've found that the problem is signing the transaction. I'm editing the question

Comment: It looks from the code like `wallet.sendTransaction` does indeed already sign the message, but nothing in the code indicates it should fail when sent an already-signed transaction. You may have found a bug, which should probably be reported in the project's GitHub issues. I think the reason to `sign` separately would be if you were going to send the transaction outside of the wallet (e.g. via a provider's `sendTransaction` method as in the [example](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#id1)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `signedTransaction` is serialized hex string of the transaction.

The `Wallet.prototype.sendTransaction` call is expecting a transaction object, not a serialized transaction. So, when it internally attempts to read `tx.to`, since tx is a string, it is getting null.

The `Provider.prototype.sendTransaction` call requires a signed transaction.

So, if you want to manually sign the transaction in your example, you could instead use:

```
wallet.provider.sendTransaction(signedTransactio);
```

Which is basically the same thing as if you had used:

```
wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
```

The main difference is that `Wallet.prototype.sendTransaction` will automatically fill in some of the values for you, and will add some utility functions to the returned transaction object (such as `wait()`)